# NGINX PHP POST METHOD not working

Tags: nginx

below code works fine in apache but not working in nginx server

```
if(isset($_POST[btn_submit]))
{
    $paper_name = addslashes($_POST[name]);
    $paper_title = addslashes($_POST[title]);
    $benefit_detail = addslashes($_POST[benefit_detail]);
    $created_date = date("Y-m-d");

    $sql_insert_paper = "INSERT INTO $tbl_cat1_master SET name = '$paper_name', benefit_detail = '$benefit_detail', title = '$paper_title', created_date = '$created_date'";
    mysql_query($sql_insert_paper);

    $sql_ins_meta = "INSERT INTO $tbl_metakeyword SET 
                page_name = '$paper_name', 
                title_desc = '$_POST[meta_title]',                  
                meta_desc = '$_POST[meta_desc]', 
                keyword_desc = '$_POST[keyword_desc]', 
                created_date = '$created_date'";
    mysql_query($sql_ins_meta);  
    header("location:cat1.php?succ=1");
}
```

Comment: there is no dependence with NGINX

Comment: Share your nginx conf - I think trouble in configuartion

Answer (score 1):

You should add single/double quotes to your POST parameters:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
...
}
```